# Getting "invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark " in adl (flash builder command-line debugger)

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex-spark, argument-dependent-lookup

Getting **"invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace:** library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"

when using adl (command-line debugger) for a flash-builder 4.6 adobe air project

its a very simple project

mxml file starts like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                                 invoke="onInvoke(event)" visible="false"> ...
```

i read about a similer problems, where solution was to swap the 
xmlns value to "http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1"/.

swapping values gave me another error :

**"invalid application descriptor: application filename must have a non-empty value"**

also,

the whole reason for this is that i have a program that must run my air app
so i need a way to run a flash-builder project in the command-line

im using adl

is this the best way ?

---

**edit :**

the descriptor file code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1"> 
    <id>exporter</id>
    <filename>exporter</filename>
    <name>exporter</name>
    <versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>
        <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </initialWindow>
</application>
```

Comment: You'r egetting a message that says "invalid Application dEscriptor".  As such I assume you are creating an AIR application.  CAn you share with us your appliation descriptor file?  That may be more useful than your main MXML File.

Comment: yes its an air app, i updated the question to include the descriptor file content

Comment: Is spark.swc included in your build path?

Comment: if the SDK version in the application-descriptor.xml from your project doesn't match the installed SDK.

Comment: Do you have Air 3.1 available for use? What is your SDK version?
I can't use Air 3.1 (and get the same error) because I removed all of the old SDK versions from Flash Builder and only have SDK 4.14.1, so I use Air 19.0, but it might be worth a check.